# Technical reason why objects were not movable in the first C++ versions?

Tags: c++

**IMPORTANT** *I'm not asking about opinions, not about what's better or not, but about the objective facts: The actual reasons that Stroustrup or other collaborators used for taking the choice of imposing that objects cannot be relocatable.*

---

I'm not able to locate the technical reason why it was decided that the address of an object cannot be changed (unfortunately any search about moving or copying objects gets cluttered with the move/copy semantics introduced later in the language).

**I mean**: C++ rightly imposes constructors when an object is copied (not doing so would go against the OOP paradigm). However, from the very beginning, it was decided that moving an object **A** from address **addr1** to **addr2** was not allowed, unless the copy constructor was invoked. What's the technical reason behind that choice? Why it was decided that its address was so important for an object?

Polymorphic objects have a pointer to their vtable, but the opposite is not true, so moving an object shouldn't break vtables. Thus, there must be another reason for it.

Also, there are other OOP languages in which objects can be freely moved. So, the OOP paradigm is not the reason.

Maybe some additional programming principles were considered undeniable when they designed the C++ language and that required to forbid moving objects? Which ones?

Comment: The technical reason is little more than nobody had articulated this, and proposed it to the C++ standards committee, and it being accepted before C++11. C++ is getting better and better. (Unlike Java which is hideously broken ;-) )

Comment: It's not that they were _absolutely_ non-movable... https://www.drdobbs.com/move-constructors/184403855

Comment: Can you locate the technical reason why C++ wasn't invented in 1970?

Comment: @Bathsheba However, they started with C, in which arrays of structs could be moved if reallocated. So, at some point, they had to have a reason for deciding that such behaviour shouldn't be allowed.

Comment: In C, nothing is moved. An array of structs isn't moved when reallocated in C. An array of structs isn't ever reallocated. What is reallocated is a bunch of bytes, and this bunch of bytes is copied (not "moved", there is no such thing in C). In C, copying a bunch of bytes is almost always  (but not really always) what you want in this case.

Comment: I can't see what vtables have to do with move-semantic! And what means *moving* an object is far away from really moving anything. It is more "pass ownership of referenced memory to new object". The object itself is never moved. I am not very lucky about the naming "move" in this case. The process of taken over ownership was possible all the time by manually writing move-functions with indeed a lot of typing overhead.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Using that rationale, C++ cannot move either, because C++ moves by first copying bytes to a new location, then discarding the previous location.

Comment: "because C++ moves by first copying bytes to a new location, then discarding the previous location". No,  that's not what moving generally does in C++.

Comment: @cesss: It feels that you have not understand what c++ move semantic means! There is no copy bytes from a to b!There is no move an object! There is only a reuse of already referenced memory *inside* the object, not the object itself!

Comment: @Klaus: With move semantics, you can implement a vector that doesn't invoke copy constructors (but move constructors instead) when it grows out of space and needs reallocation. This is what I'm talking about: The reason why it was decided that objects were bound to a fixed address in memory.

Comment: To the one who voted to close for opinion based question: I don't see how asking for the technical reason why the C++ designers took this decision would be opinion-based.

Comment: @cesss: Reallocation of memory of a vector has nothing to do with move semantic of a vector itself. The objects collected by the vector can be "moved". But moving these objects did not mean that they be moved, these objects only *can* reuse their referenced memory. For ever POD there is not any chance of moving! It still is a full deep copy! You should start reading about move semantic!

Comment: @cesss: BTW: There is no technical reason why something was not introduced earlier to a programming language. Simply some guys have the idea to do it and were able to convince others to do it. move semantic is only what is called *syntactic sugar*  and enables nothing new. It was always possible to create it manually by calling special constructors ( maybe templated once ) and so on.  But again: The object itself is kept on its address and "moving" it to another address is still not possible at all.

Comment: *"why it was decided that objects were bound to a fixed address in memory"* But they *are* bound to fixed addresses even in modern C++. "Moving" creates a new object, but unlike copying, it's allowed to change the state of the original object (e.g. a moved-from `std::vector` will be empty).

Comment: @Klaus: Maybe I'm wrong, but I thought that the new move semantics allow for (potentially but not always) faster growth of vectors by using raw low-level memory copies instead of invoking copy constructors. Anyway, even if that's not the case, take a look at this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513507/c-copy-constructor-vs-move-constructor-for-stdvector in which the first paragraph of the accepted answer contains the topic of my question: "[...] since an address is part of the definition of an object". What's the technical reason for that choice? That's my question.

Comment: @cesss "by using raw low-level memory copies instead of invoking copy constructors." Totally wrong! If the object itself is not "trivially copyable" the object must be copied or moved by the constructor or copy/move assignment operator. In case of POD, the object is always copied because there is nothing to move! PLEASE: Read what move semantic is! We have now a long list of comments from you which are all based on a totally wrong assumtion of what move in c++ means. So please: Read about move semantic and create your own code examples to get it.

Comment: @Klaus: I have edited the question, avoiding references to move semantics, and clearly focusing the question of interest, in order to avoid confusion or driving into other topics.

Comment: Moving an object from one address to another is still not allowed/done. The move for e.g. an `std::vector` is nearly identical to what you have done with `swap` before move semantics have been added. It transfers the internal data pointer and meta information from one one vector to the other. But the address of the objects does not change. In certain situations the compiler can do better optimizations with move by omitting a move, but the object itself is never moved from one address to another.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you mean by "moving an object A from address addr1 to addr2". If this a high-level description of some kind of machine code, can you describe it at a lower level?

Comment: This wasn't closed as opinion-based (solely) because the reason may be inaccessible, but because nobody knows what you think the word "move" means in the first place when you keep using it as a synonym of "copy", and it's impossible to tell if you actually understand what addresses are. The discussion is circular and futile if words keep shifting their meanings.

Comment: @Useless: It's obvious I'm talking about relocation of data. To move data is to relocate data. I don't know for any other meaning for "move" that doesn't imply relocation. A C++ object cannot be relocated, as this is imposed by the C++ standard. Incredible you cannot understand this. I'm not changing meaning, I'm always talking about the same, from the very beginning.

Comment: Relocation of data is fundamentally not a thing that ever happens. Data is _copied_. If you choose to destroy the source afterwards, that doesn't make it a relocation, it's just a destructive copy. Nothing ever changes address, because that isn't how RAM works. The C++ standard does not prevent a thing that could otherwise happen - it just refuses to provide a costly emulation of an imaginary process.

Comment: @Useless: Your comment proves that you are not correct when you claim that I've been changing meaning. I'm not to blame if your belief is that relocation doesn't exist. I really feel like being trolled: I ask for an objective question (reasons used by Stroustrup, not by you), and I get opinions such as "relocation doesn't exist". And then the question gets closed for "opinion-based". Well...

Comment: Data is never relocated, only copied. RAM physically has load and store operations, but not relocation. Addresses don't change. Since you keep using "move", "copy" and now "relocate" interchangeably, it is impossible to know if we're talking about the same thing from one comment to the next. Perhaps you really are just asking why C++ didn't add an expensive abstraction layer to permit moving objects around? Or maybe you don't really understand how memory works? I can't tell.

Comment: @Useless: I didn't use "copy" and "move" interchangeably. What I said is that "move" implies a special kind of "copy" in which objects are **not** duplicated, so it's a "move", because in a "copy" you always get two or more instances, while in a "move" you keep having just one instance (in a different address, though). Then, I said that this is what "relocation" is all about. I didn't change the meaning of the words. I'm using a coherent meaning all the time, which by the way is the common meaning in computing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)

Comment: Also, when they designed C++, the most natural choice at the time would have been relocatable objects rather than fixed-address objects, because C promotes the use of relocatable data. So, my question on why Stroustrup (and/or collaborators) decided on the contrary is very legit, and not opinion-based at all.

Comment: @cesss Ah, I've worked out what is confusing you. That only applies to objects with static duration, and it only applies before `main` begins. It's simply *ignored* by the C and C++ object models. We are talking about objects with automatic and dynamic storage duration.

Comment: @cesss To put it another way: The OS can relocate whatever it wants during startup, *before* the lifetimes of static duration objects start, and both C and C++ *don't care*.

Comment: I would believe I'm going crazy if it weren't that other people also asked questions on this topic in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411813/safely-moving-a-c-object (and... they even dare to say **"move"**... I'm not crazy!! yippee!!!) There's a difference, though: They asked if it was possible. I'm asking about the actual reasons that led Stroustrup to say in the standard that objects are bound to their address.

Comment: @cesss You are misunderstanding still. There are always two distinct objects, the source and the destination. "The object" is the one you care about. At the start, it's the source object. Then you copy + empty, so now "the object" is the destination. People are just imprecise in discussing it.

Comment: `Also, there are other OOP languages in which objects can be freely moved. So, the OOP paradigm is not the reason.` not really, it is always about the representation. In Java objects also stay at the same address in memory. It's just that a variable in Java is a reference to the object in memory. It is similar as if you would only use (smart) pointers in c++. GC languages like Java just hide this indirection. But this doesn't mean that an object can just be moved to another address.

Comment: Furthermore some containers like `std::array`, have the requirement that the object stored contiguously. Therefore the exposed addressing scheme and the one of the systems need to match and creating an abstracting addressing scheme wouldn't solve the problem that changing the address of an object without the need of doing any copy and fulfilling that the objects are stored contiguously, would conflict. In Java containers with complex objects don't store them contiguously in memory. If you want to pass the data they hold contiguously to e.g. a GPU you need to use a kind of raw Byte container.

Comment: @Caleth and others: If you want to insist that any relocation of an object implies a construction and a destruction, I'm not going to enter that debate. Your reasoning is clear: a move is a copy+destruct, so you need to call both a copy constructor and a destructor, therefore that's what Stroustrup had on mind. But that's not true. If it was, BITBLT operations on 2D framebuffers when the source and destination overlap would break: if you copy a rectangle into a position which partially overlaps it, and then you clear the source rectangle, you break it. But this is offtopic to my question.

Comment: Now let's suppose you do a memmove() of a C++ object into a destination address which is in the middle of the original object (overlapped move, which cannot be implemented by a copy and a destruction unless you use a temporary buffer --and most or all implementations of memmove() don't use a temp buffer). If relocation was allowed by the C++ specification, it would be legit to do this. But it's forbidden. The only reason I imagine to forbid this, is to automatically protect pointers to objects. If that's the reason, I'd like to locate the text where Stroustrup explained why this was important.

Comment: Nobody but you is even discussing constructors. `memcpy` _copies_ bytes. [`memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) _also_ copies bytes, just in a different order. Relocation happens in the runtime linker before execution begins, as part of building the process address map in memory. And still, there is no mechanism for an object to change address. Maybe you can edit your question to explain clearly what you believe happens, and when, in some other language you're presumably comparing to C++?

Comment: @Useless: I don't understand any of you. Are you programmers? Really? Does the C++ specification allow to memmove() a C++ object into a destination in the middle of its previous location? I'm not saying if such memove() is good practice or not. I'm not saying if storing pointers to objects is good or something that should be completely avoided. Such things would be opinion-based. What I'm asking for is fact, not opinion: I repeat for the N+1 time: Why did Stroustrup decide to impose non-relocatable objects in the C++ language.

Comment: This cannot be happening to me :-(

Comment: Because, depending on which version of your phrasing you actually intended, it either _is_ permitted (for trivial objects) or is physically impossible in the first place. Go back through your question and comments, gather up all the different variants of "copy", "move", "relocate" and "change address" and say clearly what you actually mean.

Comment: Perhaps when they're speaking casually, but if you want to have a technical discussion about object lifetime, storage and address representations, you need to be _precise_. And you used a specific phrase (_"the address of an object cannot be changed"_) which seems to suggest some very profound misunderstanding, and throws the whole discussion into confusion.

Comment: If all what you need is to know if I'm talking about what you called "trivial objects" (I call them builtin types), no I'm not talking about them. I'm talking about objects created from classes. So, if you want me to rewrite the sentence, it would be "the address of an object which was created as an instance of a class, cannot be changed". Now, if the C++ specification doesn't say this either, please ellaborate and we'll rewrite the sentence until we achieve perfection.

Comment: It sounds to us like you think "The object" means "whichever bytes contain the value I care about". If so, you have a different meaning to what C++ defines an object to be. You can transfer the value you care about to different bytes, but in C and C++ terms, that is a *new* object. That's the case both for `int` and `std::vector<std::string>`. C++ move semantics exist to allow *certain* operations on the latter to be implemented with bytewise copying, like is always possible with the former.

Comment: @Caleth: I cannot imagine from where you get the meaning _"whichever bytes contain the value I care about"_, because that's nonsense: how can you care about just some values in an object? You care about the whole memory representation of an object, not just "a value".

Comment: Let's rewrite the sentence again, in our aim to reach perfection: "the address in which it is stored the whole memory representation of an object which was created as an instance of a class, cannot be changed". If you have more suggestions for enhancing the sentence so that you can understand it without confusion, please tell. I'll keep applying your enhancements.

Comment: @Caleth: Funny that you mention move semantics now, because at the very beginning of the question I was told that my question had nothing to do with move semantics, so I rewrote the question avoiding that concept.

Comment: I think by "value" I mean the same as what you mean by "whole memory representation". Both C and C++ **define** an object as a segment of memory during an interval of time. Both allow you to interpret an object as a sequence of bytes. C has always allowed you to copy the byte values to other bytes and treat that as a new object with the same value as the original. C++ allows that *in some circumstances*.

Comment: Unless you have an answer to my actual question, or unless it is reopened in 24hours from now, so that perhaps other answers that actually answer the question can be posted, I'll delete the question. It's not a opinion-based question, as it can be clearly seen by reading the question (and very clearly expressed in its first paragraph). During the lifetime of this question, neither it nor any of my comments have been opinion-based. On the contrary, a vast number of comments have been opinion-based ("moving data doesn't exist", just to name one). If tomorrow it's still closed, I'll delete it.

Comment: @cesss it is not only about the memory but also about the behavior and lifetime. The standard allows us to use `memmove` for the data in POD objects (not the object but its data is moved - like for other languages too). If they would have allowed using `memmove` for none POD objects, then it would have been required to rephrase the section about storage duration, because what if you call `memmove` on a none POD object with automatic storage duration, how do you mark that one as having its life-time ended., so that its destructor is not called.

Comment: @cesss With dynamic and automatic storage duration you already had everything you need to accomplish moving data without an expensive copy. So it is often better to have a clear and simple description of the language (less prone to defects) then introducing a bunch of features right from the beginning. Especially if you think about what languages existed at that time and what experience the requirements and effects of possible move semantics existed at that time. Modern languages can benefit from the experience of other earlier languages and therefore add those features faster/earlier.

Comment: Also, with "other OOP languages in which objects can be freely moved" I presume you mean things like Java, C#, Python, where the language doesn't expose a particular memory location as corresponding to an object (and *implementations* of those might copy the byte representation of an object to a new location, and then update everywhere that pointed to the old location to point to the new location, for their own purposes). Those languages *also* don't let *you* the programmer relocate the representation of an object.

Comment: If you for example have `struct A { ~A() {} …};  struct B { int i; A a;} ` and `B b;` and you _move_ `b.a`, to another location, then you either need to introduce some kind of move constructor right from the beginning or add some meta information to `B` that keeps track of the lifetime of the member `a` in case you "moved" and therefore ended its lifetime. If you add meta information you have the same problem as with vtable that you aren't close to the hardware anymore and lose control over alignment and memory continuity.

Comment: And if you want to have a close to hardware language (which c++ is) then that meta-information is something you don't want to have. Alternatively, they could have chosen the way Java went, that everything is a reference, but then again you would have problems with memory continuity because `A a` then wouldn't have been fully enclosed in `B`, which is not desirable for such a language. So if you think about that there was not much of an option either add move semantics as is (copy+destruct)  from the beginning with no experience on it. Or leave it out for the moment and add it at a later.

Comment: @cesss You need to be very specific about **what your question is**, particularly what you mean by "object" and what you mean by "copy" / "move" / "relocate". You have a fine collection of answers that answer different things, because we're still guessing what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not able to locate the technical reason why it was decided that the address of an object cannot be changed

In C++ an object *is* the bytes it occupies<sup>1</sup>. Even [`std::memmove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memmove) doesn't *relocate* an object, it merely copies it's bytes. (`memmove` and [`std::memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) differ only in preconditions: `memmove` allows `[src, src + size)` to overlap `[dest, dest + size)`, `memcpy` does not)

Also you seem to have a different definition of object than what C++ has. Almost everything with a type is an object (only function types and reference types don't categorise objects). `int`s are objects, pointers (including function pointers) are objects.

A class need not have a vtable<sup>2</sup>, if it has no virtual members, or if the compiler statically knows the dynamic type at every call site.

1. plus a lifetime. Before it is created and after it is destroyed, those bytes can be something else.
2. assuming that the implementation ordinarily uses vtables to dispatch virtual functions. Other methods of dynamic dispatch are possible.

Comment: I have edited my question while you were writing your answer, in order to clarify the question better (I'm saying this just in case the edits I did in the question affect your answer somehow)

Comment: Your first line is my point of interest: "In C++ an object is the bytes it occupies". But, is it only the bytes, or the address the bytes are in?

Comment: @cesss An intrinsic property of bytes in memory is that they have an address. That's what distinguishes them from other bytes with the same value.

Comment: The "bytes it's in" is not the object, but the _region of storage_  where the object lives. 6.7.2 [intro.object]. The relevant part is also there: the region of storage of an object does not change throughout its lifetime

Comment: @MSalters: That's precisely my question: what's the technical reason why they chose to impose that _"the region of storage of an object does not change throughout its lifetime"_

Comment: @cesss You are allowed to store pointer values in files, and read them back later, so long as the object they point is still alive. How would the runtime migrate an object, changing *all* it's pointers in the face of that?

Comment: @Caleth: You wouldn't be allowed to do that if they had decided that objects aren't necessarily bound to addresses. Most of the reasons being posted aren't the reasons why objects cannot be relocated, but consequences of such choice (ie: others have said that classes can have pointers to themselves, but that's a consequence of the design, not the reason). I'm looking for the actual reason(s) that Stroustrup or others used in the design. There must be some document or draft from the late 80s or early 90s that says: "objects must be bound to addresses because...". I'm looking for that paragraph.

Comment: The funny thing is that the question has been closed because of being opinion-based. It's funny because how can be opinion-based to ask for the reasons that Stroustrup had in mind? However, it's true that most contributions are being opinion-based, because posters are saying what they believe, not what Stroustrup or other collaborators had in their minds. I'm asking for the later. Purely objective, not opinion-based.

Comment: @cesss the hardware behaviour that C models predates the idea of "relocating objects". C does the thing that naturally maps to hardware, and C++ does what C does.

Comment: @Caleth: Relocation predates C (they wrote relocatable assembly with relocatable data before C was real). And C++ doesn't do what C does. Otherwise, the C++ standard wouldn't say that objects and the address their occupy can't be independent from each other. In C, a struct (I mean the "instance of a struct" using C++ wording) is not bound to the address it occupies (it's your responsibility to decide if you want to bind it to a memory-fixed location or not, but the standard doesn't impose it). On the other hand, the C++ standard does impose that an object and its memory address are bound.

Comment: @cesss I have no idea what you mean by that. [Objects in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) also correspond to some bytes and a lifetime. There is no mechanism to relocate an object, only copy it's representation.

Answer (score 1):

> Maybe some additional programming principles were considered undeniable when they designed the C++ language and that required to forbid moving objects? Which ones?

The ones that say it should map efficiently onto the hardware implementation, which implies raw pointers, which implies address-identity.

> Also, there are other OOP languages in which objects can be freely moved. So, the OOP paradigm is not the reason

Yes, these are languages which don't mind inserting an extra layer of indirection or complexity everywhere for the convenience of the garbage collector. This is more-or-less antithetical to C++'s goals.

> it was decided that moving an object A from address addr1 to addr2 was not allowed, unless the copy constructor was invoked

The constructor is irrelevant, because in C++ *all* objects (which includes POD structs and even scalar primitives) have an identity. This identity *is* (or is bound to) their address. You can't move an `int`, either, you can only copy it. You can't move an object even *with* a copy constructor. You can't actually move an object even with a *move* constructor, because that's just a destructive copy. It doesn't pretend to mutate the address of an existing object.

> I'm not able to locate the technical reason why it was decided that the address of an object cannot be changed

Well, the address of an object can't be changed now either.

This is only ever possible in languages which hide or abstract raw pointers. C++ exposes raw references and pointers to objects, so there's no way to change an object's address without potentially breaking references to it.

If you want to make an object which is movable in the sense that the Java runtime can shuffle memory around, you need to make sure it's only ever accessible via smart pointers with the required guarantees. Since the `this` pointer will always be a raw pointer in instance methods, you have to also make sure it either *has* no instance methods, or that your smart pointers can synchronize access to prevent relocation during a call.

Comment: Nitpick: `int`s are objects too

Comment: Yeah, I need to reword that bit to distinguish between what OP thinks of as objects, and what the standard thinks of as objects. The OOP reference makes it hard to discuss `int` objects without lots of digression.

Comment: _"You can't move an int, either, you can only copy it"_  : Do you mean that if you do a raw memcpy of an int from one address to another, the copy is not a valid int?

Comment: @cesss if the destination isn't an int, no. If it is, yes. In standardising C++20 we gained language that allows an `int` object to start it's lifetime in a memcpy under certain circumstances (mainly where C says an `int` should exist)

Comment: It's a valid _copy_, you said it yourself. The original is still there. It still exists and its address hasn't changed. You just mutated another _different_ object to have the same _value_

Comment: _"[...] so there's no way to change an object's address without potentially breaking references to it"_  <-- I think this is the point. But is it actually the rationale they used? I mean, did Stroustrup or others introduce the requirement of fixed address just for protecting pointer references from one object to other objects?

Comment: It's a given in the C standard already, and as I tried to show, it's an absolute hard requirement if you want to map efficiently to the underlying machine.

Comment: @Useless: C and C++ are completely opposite in this regard: In C it is not only legal, but even encouraged by recommended books, to realloc arrays of structs, whose data is copied by low-level memory functions in case of move (ie: structs aren't copied with assignment, which would be a sort of primitive copy constructor, but their data copied with memcpy or similar). In C++ this kind of realloc is not permitted, because, as you said, objects are bound to their memory address (in C it's _your_ choice whether to consider the address bound to the data or not; in C++ it's imposed by the standard).

Comment: You're doing it again - stop it. "Copy" and "move" are not synonyms. C does _not_ move anything in the sense of changing an object's address. `memmove` does not do this, `realloc` does not do this, nothing does this, nothing has _ever_ done this, it is not an operation fundamentally supported by any hardware. `realloc` is (sometimes) a destructive copy for trivial types. Copying with `memcpy` is a **copy**, as the name suggests and _everyone has told you multiple times_. You can absolutely use `realloc` in C++ (for trivial types). You are simply wrong about everything.

Comment: @Useless: Calm down. It's much simpler than what you are saying: If you memcpy (without any copy constructor, just raw memcpy) the data of an object from address1 to address2, and then discard the copy at address1, that's a relocation (which of course implies updating references to it). Now, if a standard permits to do this, it is legit to relocate objects. If a standard forbids it (like C++), then it is not legit. Please don't complicate things. It's very simple.

Comment: Also, please, I'm not asking about what design is better or worse. I'm asking for the paragraph in some draft or document from the 90s where Stroustrup or other collaborators took the choice that objects were bound to addresses, and what reason(s) did they express for that choice. That's purely objective. The question has been closed for "opinion-based", but the question is fact-based. It is some answers the ones that are being opinion-based.

Comment: That's a copy followed by a discard ... much like the destructive copy you insisted you were not talking about. Since both source and destination objects co-exist, however briefly, it's patently obvious they're not the same object, and that the address of an object has not, in fact, been changed. The fact that you're still using copy, move, relocate as interchangeable, suggests you haven't taken on board any of the information you've been given. I'm sure you can understand that it's frustrating to attempt to help someone who keeps changing the meaning of the words they use.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the historical development of C++, you need to understand the context of that development. C++ is of course historically rooted in C. That was not a random choice. C was and is historically very important.

To look at the success of C, we need to contrast it with its contemporaries. Languages like COBOL, Algol and FORTRAN were clunky and inflexible. Languages like Lisp, Smalltalk, and Modula-2 were more elegant, but did not perform well. And in the era where C blossomed, performance was still a very pressing concern. This was well before the era of multi-Ghz multi-core CPU's. C could give you almost the performance of assembly, with far more portability and far less development cost.

But as noted, C lacks some of the features that are really relevant when developing bigger programs. Even at the original home of C, this was noted in their own products. AT&T developed their phone switch (5ESS) in a sort of Object-Oriented fashion, but using their own C language. C++ made perfect sense in that context. Improvements in compiler technology made it possible to get the benefits of OO with lower costs than doing it manually. A string type did not need to be very expensive, and it's far easier to use than C's `strcpy`.

Now C++ needed to formalize how objects worked, and this was a very early decision - it's the key development that led to the fork from C. In fact, C++ redefined the C language such that many C programs were also correct C++ programs, and the `struct` from C became an object type in C++.

Now we come to your "move"  question. In C, you can `memcpy` a struct. That would break more complex types such as strings. Even memcpy'ing a `char*` in C is fragile. The C++ solution was the copy ctor, and the assignment operator. These inventions made C++ safer compared to C++, and allowed more useful datastructures. But the very decision here defined how C++ objects work. C `structs` by default stay put, and so do C++ objects, because else a C program would not be a valid C++ program.

Comment: Thanks for talking about the historical context, because as I said in my question, I'm interested not in what's better or worse, but in the actual and objective reasons why the C++ designers (mainly Stroustrup but I leave it open just in case others took a role in this choice) decided that objects had to be bound to the memory address they occupy. I'm not clicking in any answer yet, because what I was hoping to get was some reference to some historical document or interview where Stroustrup or others explained this choice.

Answer (score 1):

I will rephrase the question as I understand the essence of it, and then answer it.

> Why reallocating an array of objects must be done by invoking constructors and destructors? Why cannot we just copy bytes of an old object to a new address and be done with it?

To reiterate, my understanding of moving in OP's terminology is *copying object's bytes to a new object* (perhaps if it is guaranteed that the original object will not be used any more). It has nothing to do with C++ move semantics.

Copying bytes does not guarantee integrity of an object, for several reasons.

1. An implementation is free to represent objects using hidden internal pointers. Objects that use multiple inheritance are often represented this way. Copying bytes to a new place invalidates these pointers. Copying bytes in this situation invalidates these pointers and destroys the integrity of the object.
2. Programmers are also free to use internal pointers. An object can contain a pointer to its own subobject. An object can also point to dependent objects which can point back to their owner. Copying bytes in this situation invalidates these pointers and destroys the integrity of the object.

The second bullet point is of course also true for C objects. But in C one cannot simply assign such objects either. Internal pointers need to be updated.

In C++, assignment always works (well, of the user wrote correct copy constructor and assignment operator). It would be unreasonable to keep assignment always working and break reallocation of certain arrays. So it was not done.

Note that a C+ compiler is allowed to byte-copy objects instead of copy-constructing them, if it can prove that it will not change the semantics of the program.

Comment: For your last point, I prefer to think of it as "In some circumstances, a compiler can implement a (sequence of) copy construction(s) as a `memcpy`"